# Verify current user authenticity from Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Parse Cloud Code function that returns some user private data given a user id. How can I verify that the given user id is indeed the id of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating this function and calling it from my other Cloud Code functions.

```
// Verifies that the given user is an authentic user
// Parameters: user
// Return: Promise
function verifyUserAuthenticity(user)
{
  var promise = new Parse.Promise();

  var userSessionToken = user.getSessionToken();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
  query.equalTo("user", user);
  query.equalTo("sessionToken", userSessionToken);
  query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(
      function(results)
      {
        if(results.length > 0)
        {
          promise.resolve("User is authentic.");
        }
        else
        {
          promise.reject("User is not authentic.");
        }
      },
      function(error)
      {
        promise.reject("Error verifying user's authenticity: " + error);
      }
    );

  return promise;
}
```